# Find a basis for the kernel and image of matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to find a basis for the kernel and image of the matrix A

$A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-12 & 6 \\
4 & -2\\
-8 & 4 \end{array} \right)$

But I am unsure how to do that.

For the kernel

$A \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
x \\
y \end{array} \right)= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0\\
0\\
0\end{array} \right)$
, I get that x = 2y.

For the Image

$A \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
x \\
y \end{array} \right)= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a\\
b\\
c\end{array} \right)$
, I get c=-2b, b=-(1/3)1 OR (1/3)a+3b+c=0

How do I write those into a basis?

Comment: There is a standard procedure to find a basis for the kernel and image of a matrix $A$. You can row-reduce $A$ to row-echelon or reduced row-echelon form. The columns that are leading in the row-echelon form tell you which columns from the original matrix $A$ you can take to get a basis for the image of $A$. For the kernel, use your row-echelon form to solve $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$, and you will get your answer in terms of a linear combination of certain vectors: those vectors form a basis for the kernel. If you have any worked examples in your notes, those would be good to look over.

Comment: I cant reduce this to reduced row echelon form because after row reduction the second and third rows become (0 0) and cant be used to reduce the first row. Plus, in this question , both basis are to be a single vector (1 vector for kernel and 1 for image)

Comment: The kernel of $A$ is all linear combintations of $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$ i.e. $\ker A = \mathrm{span}\,\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$. Since the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent, we can take the span of either column to be the image of $A$.

Comment: @Brian Thanks, what about the image basis? I need a single vector that can serve as a basis.

Comment: @MohamadMoustafa What is one vector that is in the image/ _column space_ of $A$? How does the column space relate to this one vector?

Comment: It's fine if you have rows that are all $0$'s, you can still get reduced row-echelon forms. Anyway, you can also just work with row-echelon forms (not reduced) if you want.

Comment: @Brian is it (-12,4,8)? The 2nd column is linearly dependent on the first. This leaves the first column which has a pivot. Is (-12,4,8) a basis?

Comment: @MohamadMoustafa Yes. As is the second column, as is any multiple of either. The column space of your matrix is one-dimensional, meaning that it is a line through the origin in 3d space ($\mathbb R^3$). Any vector on this line can be used to produce any other vector in the subspace by "stretching" or "shrinking", that is, multiplying it by some scalar. As such, any element of the column space can be used as a "basis" for the space.

Comment: @Brian for a matrix like (1 0 0,0 1 0,0 0 0) (Projection from 3d to xy plane). Would a basis for the kernel be (0,0,1)?

Comment: @MohamadMoustafa Yes.